# Using a specific JavaScript version (< 1.8.5)

Tags: javascript, firefox, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to test the writable property of undefined (assigning a value to undefined) using older JavaScript versions in Firefox but for some reason the code used to specify a version isn't working.

(To be more specific, versions inferior to 1.8.5 so that would be <= 1.8.2 I think.)

I was trying to test the writable property of undefined (assigning a value to undefined).

--> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

I tried this method found on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.8) :

```
<script type="application/javascript;version=1.7">
```

but it doesn't work. I also tried :

```
<script language="javascript" type="application/javascript;version=1.7">
```

and this :

```
<script language="javascript1.7" type="application/javascript">
```

but neither of them worked.

The code I tested this with is the following :

```
undefined = true;
var k;
console.log(k);
```

I also tried to substitute `undefined` with `window.undefined`, not that there is really a difference.

So my question is two-fold :

- How can I make this work in Firefox ?
- Is there a cross-browser way of achieving this ?

Thanks in advance !

EDIT: I'm using Firefox 19.

Comment: I think that the easiest method would be to use an older version of Firefox.

Comment: Is there really no other way ?

Comment: Doubtful.  It doesn't make sense.  If this is really for testing, it would be better to use that older browser anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`language="javascript1.7"` specifies a *minimum* version, not an actual version.

You will need to use an older version of the browser, one that has the version you want, to test this.

(Side-note: There are enough bugs in IE's Compatibility View, can you imagine a browser that has to implement every version of JS individually?)

Comment: Damned ! ^^ Oh well I'll download an older version of Firefox then.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers doesn't have a currenct and all previous versions of Javascript, they only have one version of Javascript.

Specifying a version for the script only makes the browser skip the script if the Javascript engine in the browser has a lower version.